# Qt WebSockets, how to send a message to client

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, server, client

I'm following this example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-echoserver-example.html but I can't figure out how to send a message to client after the connection has been made.

This seems to work but only when it's inside a function from another class.

```
void EchoServer::processTextMessage(QString message)
{

    m_clients.at(0)->sendTextMessage("test");

}
```

Where / How should I put the code to get it working?

e. g. How to send a message to client after a button has been pressed in MainWindow?

This is working

```
void EchoServer::processTextMessage(QString message)
{

      m_clients.at(0)->sendTextMessage("test");

}
```

This isn't working

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_clients.at(0)->sendTextMessage("test");

}
```

Neither this

```
void MainWindow::myclicked()
{

 m_clients.at(0)->sendTextMessage("test");

}
```

Comment: Make sure you run 2 separate processes and the client supposed to open QWebsocket and listen to *received signal. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html It started working for me with sendTextMessage for the server and textMessageReceived handled signal for the client right away when I tried the first time. And now that works in production code with our own server not to mention "ping-pong".

Comment: The example code works fine and the echo message is returned to client also. I don't understand where and how I put the sendTextMessage to get the message from server to client. e. g. How to send a message to client after a button has been pressed in MainWindow?

Comment: You have to have 2 QWebsocket's running, not one. One does sendTextMessage and the other listens on its signal textMessageReceived. And there a special server between them so that the push works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Here is the code:

```
QWebSocket *messageSocket;


void EchoServer::onNewConnection()
{
    QWebSocket *pSocket = m_pWebSocketServer->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(pSocket, &QWebSocket::textMessageReceived, this, &EchoServer::processTextMessage);
    connect(pSocket, &QWebSocket::disconnected, this, &EchoServer::socketDisconnected);


    m_clients << pSocket;

    messageSocket=pSocket;
}



void MainWindow::myclicked()
{
    if (messageSocket)
        {

             messageSocket->sendTextMessage("test");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple WebSocket clients, the following code will send a message to each client in the list if there are any:

```
void MainWindow::myclicked()
{
  if (m_clients.isEmpty())
    return;

  for (auto pClient : m_clients)
  {
    if (pClient)
      pClient->sendTextMessage("test");
  }
}
```